# Confusing question on $\sigma$ algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

If $A \subset \sigma(B)$, does it mean $A \subset B$ ? Here $\sigma(B)$ implies the minimal $\sigma$ field generated by $B$.

Comment: No, unless $B=\sigma(B)$.

Comment: How can you show that? I know that if $\sigma(B)=B$ then it follows. But how to show the other way round that $B$ has to be $\sigma(B)$?

Answer (score 3):

Take $B = \{\emptyset\}$ and $A=\{X\}$. Now $\sigma(B) = \{\emptyset, X\}$.